# Безопасность контейнера

Tags: docker, безопасность

Насколько секьюрно базовый образ делать так:

```
RUN apk add openssh git make

ARG CI_JOB_TOKEN
ARG CI_REGISTRY
ARG CI_GIT
ARG CI_JOB_USER

RUN git config --global url."https://${CI_JOB_USER}:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@git.***.ru".insteadOf "https://git.***.ru"
```

?

Какие есть альтернативы?

Comment: задаем переменную CI_JOB_USER как что то вида `" && echo "bu" || echo "`.

Comment: @KoVadim это внутренняя переменная гитлаба. Не думаю что ее можно переопределить. ТС, вы `git config --global` используете чтобы дальше в контейнере что-то собирать? Тогда есть другой способ сборки, гитлаб сам скачивает репу, нужно только собрать, в том числе в докере, и делается это по-другому.

Comment: @TotalPusher а как быть с зависимостями, которые подтягиваются из гитлаба в go, например?